# Change Talkback language dynamically?

Tags: java, android, accessibility, talkback

I have an application with a translation quiz and I want to make it accessible to blind people. The problem is that when I focus on a Spanish sentence (for example), Talkback reads it in English. Is there any way to trigger the Spanish TTS dynamically in Java?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is now!

You have to wrap the string in a `LocaleSpan` (min sdk 17) and the latest version of TalkBack can switch language on the fly.

- What's new in Android Accessibility 2017 - https://youtu.be/h5rRNXzy1xo?t=11m
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/LocaleSpan.html