# Android App Accessibility: How can I define the app main language?

Tags: android, accessibility, screen-readers, wcag

In the European Standard for Accessibility there is a requirement that the "default human language of software can be programmatically determined".

For example, when using a Spanish-language app on an English-language Android operating system, the Spanish terms should not be read aloud in an English pronunciation, by the talkback screenreader.

However, I cannot find a way to fulfill this requirement.
Is there a way in Android to specify in the code which language the app should report to the system?

Comment: Have you seen: [Change Talkback language dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44346134/295004)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Talkback language dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346134/change-talkback-language-dynamically)

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? The comments above this one are not very helpful since they're TextView specific and not global